# R: conditional grep all occurrences of a character string

Tags: r, regex, string

I am trying to parse character strings based on 2 conditions:

- Must have only 1 character on either side of the /
- Must be able to parse all occurrences within the same cell

Below is my attempt to try and achieve this task. Except, I am unable to parse "Apples B/ E Greens T/A Parsley". I would please like to know how can I grep a cell regardless of where it occurs.

Thanks in advance.

```
col.df <- c("N/A", "Apples and Oranges", "H/E Carrots", "Apples B/ E Greens T/A Parsley", "B/E Greens T/A Parsley", "WATER/SODA")

slash.title = "(^[A-Z]{1}/)"
sort(unique(col.df[grep(slash.title, col.df)]))

[1] "B/E Greens T/A Parsley" "H/E Carrots"            "N/A"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this

```
sort(unique(grep("\\b[A-Z]/[A-Z]\\b", col.df, value=T)))
```

Here I use `\b` which indicates a work boundary. So there must be either a space or the end of the string after and before each single letter.

It returns

```
[1] "Apples B/ E Greens T/A Parsley" "B/E Greens T/A Parsley"  "H/E Carrots"                   
[4] "N/A"
```

Comment: Just put `{1}` after each `[A-Z]`.

Comment: @l'L'l Why is the `{1}` necessary or helpful? `grep("[A-Z]{1}\\/[A-Z]{1}","AA/BB", value=T)` returns "AA/BB" which is not a match as I understand it.

Comment: @MrFlick, It should only return A/B with exactly the number of {n} used as the quantifier; it doesn't work that way for you? [info here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html). btw - USE the `\b` boundry! your example above doesn't show it.

Comment: @l'L'l But `grep("\\b[A-Z]\\/[A-Z]\\b",col.df, value=T)` is the exact same as `grep("\\b[A-Z]{1}\\/[A-Z]{1}\\b",col.df, value=T)` I don't understand what's the point of adding `{1}`. The character classes as i've written them will only match one character already.

Comment: No, its behavior in using regular expressions, `[A-Z]` will match a character of `A` to `Z`, by adding the `{1}` it is matching the same thing.